# Documents not appearing in Primary Results - Sharepoint online - (Sharepoint search query tool)

Tags: sharepoint-online

[image]

The documents in the player bios library (screenshot above) do not seem to be getting picked up by my search api end points (See search query tool).

In the advanced settings for this document library, Allow items from this document library to appear in search results has been selected YES.

The documents are a few days old now, so definitely would of been crawled.

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

A few things to check:

1. What if you deselect “Trim Duplicates” under Query? Per my test in my environment, it returns 6 more results with “Trim Duplicates” deselected.
2. Type “Another 1” in the query box and see if you can get the file in the result.
3. Change the SharePoint Site URL to `https://bpkintelogydev.sharepoint.com/sites/dsfdsf`.
4. Specify the “Result Source Id” under Query, for example, Local SharePoint Results.

   There is one scenario during the test I cannot figure out why.

   If I set the “Result Source Id” as Local SharePoint Results, the tool returns 30 results, while it returns 110 results when I set the “Result Source Id” as Documents.

   You can change the "Result Source Id" to see if you can get the document.

[image]